# Why does Nautilus slow down every time I delete file?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, compiz

I am using Gnome Classic in Ubuntu 14.10, with Compiz effects.

Whenever I delete a file in a Nautilus window, the window becomes unresponsive, and goes grey for a few seconds. Then, it returns. It's a very annoying slowdown for such a simple operation.

So far as I can tell, this only happens when deleting files, not with any other operation.

Why is this happening, and, far more importantly, how do I get it so that file deletion is more or less instantaneous, as it has been up until recently. This change may have happened after upgrading to 14.10. I can't be sure, but that's roughly when I started noticing.

Comment: Do you delete by sending the files to Trash or you completely delete them (Shift+Delete) ?

Comment: @hakermania, I just press Delete.

Comment: Then nautilus sends your files to Trash. Maybe your Trash contains way to many files? What happens if you empty your Trash and then try to delete some other file? Does it still hang?

Comment: @hakermania, yes, it hangs even if trash is empty.

Comment: I'm seeing this when completely deleting files after upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity to 14.10. I have two machines and only see this on one. I can't provoke it by creating new files and then deleting them.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? Do you use anything like LVM or MDADM? Are the files located on a regular harddisk or an SSD? Does this also happen when you delete files in the Unity desktop?

Comment: @ph0t0nix, I'm not sure what you mean by filesystem, but ext4 maybe? I don't know what LVM or MDADM are. It's not an SSD. I haven't tried Unity yet, but I suppose I could give that a try sometimes when I don't have to use the computer for work.

Comment: Indeed, Ext4 is the most likely candidate for a file system. Since you don't know what the LVM and MDADM are we can safely forget about those.

Comment: I have seen the issue when using an NTFS file system. Today I deleted some files in there using Nautilus, but there were no issues this time.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with video files after seeing them with VLC. Suspect that VLC is keeping the file locked for too long, or even failing to release some kind of lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the problem in my case was that a Virtual Machine was trying to access the same directory while I was using it, causing some kind of slow down. If I don't use the directory when the Virtual Machine is running, or don't have the Virtual Machine on when accessing the directory, there is no slow down.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by reinstalling nautilus.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

I hope this helps,

C.